# Dropdown list showing vertically in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-5

I am debugging my application for internet explorer 11 and below and, for some reason, dropdownlists have a tendency of showing vertically instead of horizontally.

Say I have these lines of code:

```
@model MagicAdmin2.Utility.PageFilters.CardSetFilter

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="filters" class="blackBorder defaultBaseStyle whiteField" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <h3 style="background: white; margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 10px; padding: 0 10px; width: 50px;">Filters</h3>
        Category: @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.mCategory, Model.mCategoryList, new { disabled = "disabled", @id = "setCategory"}) 
        Block: @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.mBlock, Model.mBlockList, "All", new {@id = "setBlock"}) 
        Cards Loaded:@Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.mHasCards, Model.mHasCardsList, new {@id = "setLoaded"})
        <input type="button" value="Search" id="fetchButton" onclick="needToConfirm=false"/>
    </div>
}
```

I'll show the three main classes of the div to avoid confusion in the css:

```
.blackBorder {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.defaultBaseStyle {
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.whiteField {
    background-color: white;
}
```

And the internet explorer scripts in which I have tried the following:

```
#filters ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left
}
```

based on a few answers I found here and there on stackoverflow. However, I do not have any luck so far. Here's how I check for internet explorer browser:

```
<!--[if IE]> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" title="text/css" href="/Content/IEStyle.css"/>
        <![endif]-->
```

** EDIT **

Here's a quick html output of the partial view as rendered:

```
<h2>Cards Display Results</h2>
<br/>

<form action="/Card/DisplayCardsResults" method="post">    <div id="filters"class="blackBorder defaultBaseStyle whiteField" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <h3 style="background: white; margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 10px; padding: 0 10px; width: 50px;">Filters</h3>
        Filter by card name: <input id="cardNameFilter" name="mCardName" type="text" value="" />
        set: <select class="dropdownList" id="cardSetFilter" name="CardSet"><option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Khans of Tarkir">Khans of Tarkir</option>
<option value="Magic 2015 Core Set">Magic 2015 Core Set</option>
<option value="Magic: The Gathering—Conspiracy">Magic: The Gathering—Conspiracy</option>
<option value="Journey into Nyx">Journey into Nyx</option>
<option value="Born of the Gods">Born of the Gods</option>
<option value="Commander 2013 Edition">Commander 2013 Edition</option>
<option value="Theros">Theros</option>
<option value="Magic 2014 Core Set">Magic 2014 Core Set</option>
<option value="Modern Masters">Modern Masters</option>
<option value="Dragon&#39;s Maze">Dragon&#39;s Maze</option>
<option value="Gatecrash">Gatecrash</option>
<option value="Commander&#39;s Arsenal">Commander&#39;s Arsenal</option>
<option value="Return to Ravnica">Return to Ravnica</option>
<option value="Magic 2013">Magic 2013</option>
<option value="Planechase 2012 Edition">Planechase 2012 Edition</option>
<option value="Avacyn Restored">Avacyn Restored</option>
<option value="Dark Ascension">Dark Ascension</option>
<option value="Innistrad">Innistrad</option>
<option value="Magic 2012">Magic 2012</option>
<option value="New Phyrexia">New Phyrexia</option>
<option value="Mirrodin Besieged">Mirrodin Besieged</option>
<option value="Scars of Mirrodin">Scars of Mirrodin</option>
<option value="Magic 2011">Magic 2011</option>
<option value="Rise of the Eldrazi">Rise of the Eldrazi</option>
<option value="Worldwake">Worldwake</option>
<option value="Zendikar">Zendikar</option>
<option value="Planechase">Planechase</option>
<option value="Magic 2010">Magic 2010</option>
<option value="Alara Reborn">Alara Reborn</option>
<option value="Conflux">Conflux</option>
<option value="Shards of Alara">Shards of Alara</option>
<option value="Eventide">Eventide</option>
<option value="Shadowmoor">Shadowmoor</option>
<option value="Morningtide">Morningtide</option>
<option value="Lorwyn">Lorwyn</option>
<option value="Tenth Edition">Tenth Edition</option>
<option value="Future Sight">Future Sight</option>
<option value="Planar Chaos">Planar Chaos</option>
<option value="Time Spiral">Time Spiral</option>
<option value="Coldsnap">Coldsnap</option>
<option value="Dissension">Dissension</option>
<option value="Guildpact">Guildpact</option>
<option value="Ravnica: City of Guilds">Ravnica: City of Guilds</option>
<option value="Ninth Edition">Ninth Edition</option>
<option value="Saviors of Kamigawa">Saviors of Kamigawa</option>
<option value="Betrayers of Kamigawa">Betrayers of Kamigawa</option>
<option value="Champions of Kamigawa">Champions of Kamigawa</option>
<option value="Fifth Dawn">Fifth Dawn</option>
<option value="Mirrodin">Mirrodin</option>
<option value="Eighth Edition">Eighth Edition</option>
<option value="Scourge">Scourge</option>
<option value="Legions">Legions</option>
<option value="Darksteel">Darksteel</option>
<option value="Onslaught">Onslaught</option>
<option value="Judgment">Judgment</option>
<option value="Torment">Torment</option>
<option value="Odyssey">Odyssey</option>
<option value="Apocalypse">Apocalypse</option>
<option value="Seventh Edition">Seventh Edition</option>
<option value="Planeshift">Planeshift</option>
<option value="Invasion">Invasion</option>
<option value="Prophecy">Prophecy</option>
<option value="Nemesis">Nemesis</option>
<option value="Mercadian Masques">Mercadian Masques</option>
<option value="Urza&#39;s Destiny">Urza&#39;s Destiny</option>
<option value="Classic Sixth Edition">Classic Sixth Edition</option>
<option value="Urza&#39;s Legacy">Urza&#39;s Legacy</option>
<option value="Urza&#39;s Saga">Urza&#39;s Saga</option>
<option value="Exodus">Exodus</option>
<option value="Stronghold">Stronghold</option>
<option value="Tempest">Tempest</option>
<option value="Weatherlight">Weatherlight</option>
<option value="Fifth Edition">Fifth Edition</option>
<option value="Visions">Visions</option>
<option value="Mirage">Mirage</option>
<option value="Alliances">Alliances</option>
<option value="Homelands">Homelands</option>
<option value="Ice Age">Ice Age</option>
<option value="Fourth Edition">Fourth Edition</option>
<option value="Fallen Empires">Fallen Empires</option>
<option value="The Dark">The Dark</option>
<option value="Legends">Legends</option>
<option value="Revised Edition">Revised Edition</option>
<option value="Antiquities">Antiquities</option>
<option value="Unlimited Edition">Unlimited Edition</option>
<option value="Arabian Nights">Arabian Nights</option>
<option value="Limited Edition Beta">Limited Edition Beta</option>
<option value="Limited Edition Alpha">Limited Edition Alpha</option>
</select>
        rarity: <select class="dropdownList" id="cardRarityFilter" name="mRarity"><option value="All">All</option>
<option value="L">Land</option>
<option value="C">Common</option>
<option value="U">Uncommon</option>
<option value="R">Rare</option>
<option value="M">Mythic Rare</option>
</select>
        type: <select class="dropdownList" id="cardTypeFilter" name="mType"><option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Artifact">Artifact</option>
<option value="Instant">Instant</option>
<option value="Creature">Creature</option>
<option value="Land">Land</option>
<option value="Planeswalker">Planeswalker</option>
<option value="Enchantment">Enchantment</option>
<option value="Sorcery">Sorcery</option>
</select>
        color: <select class="dropdownList" id="cardColorFilter" name="mColor"><option value="All">All</option>
<option value="W">White</option>
<option value="R">Red</option>
<option value="G">Green</option>
<option value="U">Blue</option>
<option value="B">Black</option>
<option value="O">Gold</option>
<option value="N">Colorless</option>
</select>
        <input type="button" value="Search" id="fetchButton" onclick="needToConfirm=false"/>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: is the form element wide enough to accomodate the `select` elements ? (*check it with the console*)

Comment: Theirs no need to make an IE specific stylesheet here. Can you post up the actual html output for us to better understand what's going on?

Comment: I've started a specific IE sheet in case I had to do specific css styling because IE was not as "compromising" as other browsers. As for the HTML output, I'll dig it and put it in a minute with pleasure.

Comment: I'm just saying that nowadays IE specific stylesheets aren't really needed. some would argue w/ me.. but we mainly deal w/ IE8+ , if you write your css correctly the browsers can all play nicely together.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a nice way to do things if I was not still clumsy with IE css ;) That's a good advice tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually tested this yet in IE11, but I think the main problem is your css here isn't actually targeting anything,

```
 #filters ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left
}
```

What I think* you meant to do is something like this:

```
 #filters select {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left
}
```

I took a slightly different approach to the html/css so I could make things a bit more simple: http://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/L8wvcppb/1/

Let me know if that works.

Comment: You more then likely have some conflicting styles going on that are affecting your layout. I checked in IE11 and everything looked fine in my js fiddle. Do you have a live version of the code anywhere?

Comment: You were right on that one, I went through the code and finally found a place where the display of those dropdownlist was on TABLE display... talk of a way to f*** things up. Thanks a lot! :)